# 'Starting with the' or 'starting the' & 'from at least OR at least from'

Tags: phrase-requests, phrase-usage

1. Which one would be correct,
   a. We will be starting with the interview process on 5th October OR
   b. We will be starting the interview process on 5th October

2
a. You should get coins at least from... OR
b. You should get coins from at least

I also want to know the logic/reasoning behind the correct answer. I am getting confused a lot these days in such cases. Is there any book that I can read and start understanding what's correct and what's not?

Answer (score 1):

"Starting with the X" would normally mean that X is just the first step in the things we are doing. So "We will be starting with the interview process on October 5th, and then moving on to the psychological testing on October 10th". If interviewing is the only process (that we are talking about) then you would normally say "We will be starting the interview process...".

However common usage means that either is likely to be understood and therefore acceptable.